# What is the recommended way to fix line break issues in posts?

Tags: discussion

Today I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211146/2615940) in the Late Answers review queue. It is obvious that the new user did not understand how newlines appear in posts. When I clicked edit to look at the original text, there were some line breaks that did not appear in the output because the previous lines did not have two spaces at their ends.

I wanted to edit the post because his/her intentions were clear, but edits are required to be more than 6 characters, and I don't think trailing whitespace additions count. I believe the readability of that post could be greatly improved by applying the author's intended line breaks.

A workaround would be to manually add the html <\br>, but I suspect I would get my edits rejected for hacky workarounds like that.

Also, I know the answer isn't great and could use some rewording as well. However, I don't know the language or topic at hand well enough to improve the technical content of the answer, and I don't think it's quite bad enough to flag. Someone more experienced in that field would be in a better position to tell if its a worthwhile answer or not. Fixing the line breaks is the only significant improvement I feel qualified to make.

What is the suggested course of action if a post needs line breaks fixed, but I don't have any other non-trivial edits to make?

Comment: Actually, if you need to pad your edit, better to use a html comment: `<!-- -->`. Still, use a good edit summary and be sure there's nothing else left to improve.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything about edit padding here on Meta, but I would expect it to be frowned upon. Any idea how the community feels about edit padding if the editor feels like they have nothing else to contribute?

Comment: If they concurr that there's nothing else which should be done, use the least annoying padding, and it should be approved if it's a good edit. Otherwise, it should be rejected as too minor, or by editing and *not* indicating helpfulness. (Though it has good chances of being approved either way).

Comment: You can also add a Javascript comment to take up space. Its not displayed in the post. I think I read that trick here. And please don't add the `<\br>`. Its something that others will have to remove later if its re-edited after you edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep participating on the site. Once you reach high enough reputation, you'll be able to make those line break fixing edits without this message about six characters. I just checked, by adding only a couple trailing spaces to your question.

Comment: Any idea what that threshold is? I assume 2k since that's when edits are applied immediately.

Comment: Your assumption is right. Just keep participating, you're almost halfway there :)

Comment: I rolled back your edit, I hope you don't mind. :)