# Unable to do short but necessary edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Hi I tried to edit https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229214/473890 because both regexes aren't closed by a quote character. Of course that edit only adds two characters and as soon as I do submit it, I get an error that I have to change at least 6 characters.

Apart from randomly changing the content to get to those 6 charachter what can be done then? I wrote a short comment to notify any reader but is that the best solution?

Comment: It was just corrected.

Comment: Related: [What is wrong with minor edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits)

Comment: This is a common question on meta actually.

Comment: @LéoLam no, it's not dupe of that one.

Comment: It's not; your comment came in just as I edited the comment to "related"

Comment: @LéoLam thought you cast a flag. Anyway, there is a very related feature request on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags

Comment: Get 2k and [do short but necessary edits.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/268306/revisions)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268192/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-fix-line-break-issues-in-posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in those cases you can comment (that is one of the reasons they exist) and notify the author that their code is wrong.

If you were interested in really editing the question, you would have to work until you have at least 2000 rep ;)